# 6 Visitors to Econ.SE daily?

Tags: discussion, support

A strange statistic on the site activity is being posted. Why is this the case?

[image: a bit of a stranger report]

On the main site:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with Stack Exchange sites currently: [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51). SE employees are aware...